# How to get port name of printer?

Tags: java, printing

I use javax.print.PrintService to look up printer services on local machine. 
Here is code to get printers:

```
PrintService[] services = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(DocFlavor.SERVICE_FORMATTED.PRINTABLE, null);
```

Can i also get port name of printer (USB001, COM, LPT..) in java?

Answer (score 0):

You just can't do it with pure Java code (i.e., without using JNI (native code)).

Comment: Hello,
Please give me a guidance or link for reference. Thank you!
Regards,
Minhbt

Comment: Hey, You can get port name of printer only on a specific os (WINDOWS XP professional) by trying to access private method getPort() of Win32PrintService . It return port name of printer. By the way, how can i retrieve printer model ?